# rosjava groovy install fail

Tags: ros-groovy, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey

I have downloaded rosjava_core into "~/catkin_ws/src/rosjava_core".

I am using Java version:
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.3) (6b27-1.12.3-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

Although trying with JDK 7 still produces the same error.

Installing rosjava in groovy after the catkin update and receiving an error when running catkin make from "~/catkin_ws"(see below for print out).

Error message in print out

19 errors
:rosjava_test:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':rosjava_test:compileJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Has anyone encountered this error in groovy or previous versions? Searching has found some results but no solution to the problem as far as I can find.

EDIT:
After a bit more debugging it saying "Pakcage test_ros does not exist"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61895/rosjava-groovy-install-fail/) by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2013-04-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, found a solution however it is not a proper fix, although works.

First I found test_ros was not being generated inside "rosjava_core/rosjava_messages/build/generated-src".

Taking test_ros from a previous compilation of rosjava (different computer running fuerte), I placed this folder inside the generated-src folder.

Running ./gradlew or catkin_make, then ran a successful build.

This is not a proper fix, and I have put a issue under the git repo for rosjava, hopefully someone who knows the system a bit better than I do can solve it.

Henry

---

Originally posted by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) with karma: 140 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HenryW](https://answers.ros.org/users/3316/henryw/) on 2013-05-26**:
solution has been found, details are on the git repo for rosjava: https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/issues/156#issuecomment-18445073